# Zabbix Mattermost notification integrations - Timeout exceeded while connecting to 'localhost' when testing Mattermost Media Type

Tags: zabbix, mattermost

I am trying to intergrate our mattermost with zabbix to receive notifications on alerts. I've followed up the instructions on [this link](https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/mattermost). We are using Zabbix 4.4 with MM 5.19.
After enabling the integration, No alerts are being posted on Mattermost. I tried testing the Media type on Administration > Media Types > Mattermost > Test.
I've added the following as the parameters, but it throws the error : Connection timeout of 3 seconds exceeded when connecting to Zabbix server "localhost".

```
bot_token : {Token generated for the Bot in Mattemost}
mattermost_url : {https://mattermost.our-company.com}
send_mode : alarm
```

Tried changing {ZABBIX_URL} to both http://127.0.0.1 and http://zabbix.our-company.com (The DNS is resolved only internally, but our mattermost is available on public network) but none of them work.
I checked the logs inside /var/log/zabbix but no error or anything. I even tried putting the zabbix logs to Debug mode but no luck in any case, the only Debug log I've got is the following :

```
2063:20200216:090224.146 trapper got '{"request":"alert.send","sid":"74095b240dd6783618571516f029187a","data":{"parameters":{"zabbix_url":"{$ZABBIX.URL}","send_mode":"alarm","send_to":"{ALERT.SENDTO}","event_tags":"{EVENT.TAGS}","event_name":"{EVENT.NAME}","event_nseverity":"{EVENT.NSEVERITY}","event_ack_status":"{EVENT.ACK.STATUS}","event_value":"{EVENT.VALUE}","event_update_status":"{EVENT.UPDATE.STATUS}","event_date":"{EVENT.DATE}","event_time":"{EVENT.TIME}","event_severity":"{EVENT.SEVERITY}","event_opdata":"{EVENT.OPDATA}","event_id":"{EVENT.ID}","event_update_message":"{EVENT.UPDATE.MESSAGE}","trigger_id":"{TRIGGER.ID}","trigger_description":"{TRIGGER.DESCRIPTION}","host_name":"{HOST.NAME}","host_ip":"{HOST.IP}","event_update_date":"{EVENT.UPDATE.DATE}","event_update_time":"{EVENT.UPDATE.TIME}","event_recovery_date":"{EVENT.RECOVERY.DATE}","event_recovery_time":"{EVENT.RECOVERY.TIME}","bot_token":"qs3rkqdappy6i8gs3a8871phxc","mattermost_url":"https:\/\/mattermost.our-company.com"},"mediatypeid":"7"}}'
```

What can be the issue? Is there a way to "debug" and find the root cause of this error? Any help is appreciated! Note that right now we have integrated Slack with Zabbix and it's working fine, but we are moving to Mattermost and therefore, we need to migrate the integrations as well.

Comment: Is that `{$ZABBIX.URL}` (with a dot) or `{$ZABBIX_URL}` (underscore)? I don't think the first one will work.

Comment: its `{$ZABBIX_URL}`, I'm working on a possibility that the problem is network-based, but not on zabbix, but between MatterMost and zabbix...I will update the question (or probably answer it) when I get a chance and sit with our Network Admin.

Comment: i asked because in the debug log you showed {$ZABBIX.URL}, which is empty and possibly causing your issue

Comment: I double-checked. You were right. Under Configuration > General > Macros I had ZABBIX.URL, so I changed it to ZABBIX_URL. But the issue persists. I still haven't been able to sit with Network Admin, ASA I get the chance, I will update this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the issue with our Network Admin. The problem was that our Zabbix server was trying to resolve Mattermost name from local network route (i.e. 192.168.x.x) and it kept failing, therefore, no SSL connection could be initiated.
It seems that Zabbix integration tests' error messages are quite generic and sometimes, misleading. Thorough investigation is needed for finding out the root cause.